# Angularjs : use of $httpProvider for handling "500 error" from server

Tags: angularjs

I want to use $httpProvider to handle "500 error" sent by Server (J2EE).
I don't know how to inject it in my application :

```
angular
        .module('rhTechvalleyApp', [
            'ngStorage', 
            'ngResource',
            'ngCookies',
            'ngAria',
            'ngCacheBuster',
            'ngFileUpload',
            'ui.bootstrap',
            'ui.bootstrap.datetimepicker',
            'ui.router',
            'infinite-scroll',
            'angular-loading-bar',
            'ngTable',
            'ngContextMenu',
            'ui.select',
            'ngSanitize',
            'ui.bootstrap.contextMenu',
            'jkuri.slimscroll'
        ])
        .run(run);

    run.$inject = ['stateHandler'];

    function run(stateHandler) {
        stateHandler.initialize();

    }
```

If anyone can help me on this